# filter by text in specifiec property

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of objects, like those

```
{ name: "task1", owner: "david", des: "task1 description" },
{ name: "task2", owner: "Smith", des: "task2 description" },
{ name: "task1", owner: "david", des: "task1 description" },
```

also a `select` and `textbox`
and a table that shows them all.

i am looking a way to `filter`, the data in the table.
The user will select a value from drop-down and enter text in the textbox.

Then the table data will be filtered by text matches in selected value (object property) from drop-down.

Example:

- choosing "name" from dropdown and write "task" in textbox will return all 3 items in array. text word is contained within all 3 records.
- choosing "name" from dropdown and write "task1" in textbox will return record 1 and 3.

textbox value will be **required for the filter to happen**.

Can it be done with angularjs filter?

https://plnkr.co/edit/Afs7MOIziUOvFWzBY7qf?p=preview

Comment: The demo on the filter documentation page does almost that: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter. So the answer to your question is yes, it can be done.

Comment: I updated my plunker, i can't seem to make it work - can you pleasse tell me what i do wrong? + also, i want thew filter to heppen **only** if the textbox is Not empty, how can i achieve it?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/kCI875Qg9FKccpMlF6gY?p=preview

Comment: your plunker doesn't work for me, i chose "name" entered text "task" and nothing happend, also what should i do to filter only by the text when the user dont select from dropdown

Comment: It works fine for me. It shows all tasks because the word 'task' is in every name!

Comment: Well, all your rows have a name containing "task", so it you enter "task", they all stay there.

Comment: my mistake :) sorry.. please write your answer so i can accept it

Comment: I updated my plunker and added another option to dropdown, when this option "filter by" is chosen in the dropdown and the use enter some text - it looks for that, resulting no results - how can it be ignored? (only when this option is selected) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ng-disabled` property on `text-box`

Working [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/yqihyM1W1f1AbqN5ABDs?p=preview)

Html need to update

```
<input ng-model="filterdata[filterProperty]" type="text" ng-disabled="!filterProperty" />
```

Answer (score 0):

At that point it's probably easiest to write a custom filter. Custom filters are very easy and straightforward and allow you to control all aspects of how and when the filter is applied. Here is a working sample for your case - it's not very robust because it will break if you try to filter a numeric property, but it gives you the gist and something to build on and customize for your needs.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cards = [{
        name: "task1",
        owner: "david",
        des: "task1 description"
      },
      {
        name: "task2",
        owner: "Smith",
        des: "task2 description"
      },
      {
        name: "task3",
        owner: "Smith",
        des: "task3 description"
      },
      {
        name: "task4",
        owner: "Davis",
        des: "task4 description"
      },
      {
        name: "task5",
        owner: "Thomas",
        des: "task5 description"
      },
      {
        name: "task6",
        owner: "david",
        des: "task6 description"
      }
    ];
  })
  .filter('myFilter', function() {
    return function(items, property, value) {
      // if items, property or value are missing return items by default
      if (!items || !property || !value) {
        return items;
      }
      // create an array to hold the matched items
      var out = [];
      angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        // see if the item property value contains the desired value
        if (item[property].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())) {
          out.push(item);
        }
      });
      // return the array of items
      return out;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>
      <select ng-model="filterProperty">
          <option value="">filter by</option>
          <option value="name">name</option>
          <option value="owner">owner</option>
          <option value="des">des</option>
        </select>
      <input ng-model="filterData" type="text" />
    </div>
    <table style="border: 1px solid">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>owner</th>
          <th>description</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in cards | myFilter:filterProperty:filterData">
          <td>{{x.name}}</td>
          <td>{{x.owner}}</td>
          <td>{{x.des}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: the plunker that i made is a simple one that descrtibe my problem. but in  the real app i have, if i want to use custom filters i'll need to run over with 3 for loops, cause i dont show the data within a table, the app is similier to Github kanban board - i will need to use 1'st for loop to look for the specific board > then for the specific category > and the for the specific card. i think that @Gaurav will be the way to solve it quickly. Thanks